# MVC3 Default value for a DateTime property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, default

I have a DateTime property on one of my Model classes and want to set it's default vaule to Now.  The below code is what I had hoped would work but won't compile.  It doesn't like the System.DateTime.Now call:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "To Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "To Date is required.")]
    [DefaultValue(System.DateTime.Now)]
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you really need to double post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891519/mvc3-htmlhelper-defaults

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the model class:

```
private DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime Date 
{
  get { return _date; }
  set { _date = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In C# 6 or higher you can set a default value to an auto property.

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

This is logically the same as the below code, use this for older version of C#, just shorter way of writing.

```
private DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return _date; }
    set { _date = value; }
}
```

The above two ways will always return the current date & time. It will set the time when the object is constructed and always return that time there after. To always return the current latest date & time use a get property.

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return DateTime.Now; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ctor()
{
   DateTo = DateTime.Now;
}
```

But beware, when returning `View()` that expects your object as model. You should always pass the objcet like `View(new MyObject())`, otherwise constructor won't be invoked and you won't get default value on `DateTo`.

Your code does not compile because Attributes need compile-time constants as parameters. `DateTime.Now` is not constant, so compiler complies.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to set DefaultValue to DateTime.Now because DateTime.Now is a method, I suggest you change the default constructor to set DateTo = DateTime.Now it will have the same effect.

Comment: See the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx

Comment: DateTime.Now is Property, definitely not method. And even it is propety, the case is that Attributes need compile time constants as parameters.