# Bind DateTime.Now using MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like to **hard-code DateTime.Now** (on the front end) **when a new record is created**. However I don't want to see the fields as they're not going to need input. Using the code listed below I'm throwing "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*"

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tbl_one tbl_one)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.tbl_one.Add(tbl_one);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(tbl_one);
}
```

**Model**:

```
public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

**View**:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created, Model.Created = DateTime.Now)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Created)
</div>
```

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created, Model.Created = DateTime.Now)

Answer (score 2):

Partial Credit to: [MVC3 HTMLHelper defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891519/mvc3-htmlhelper-defaults)

Fix:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created, new { @Value = System.DateTime.Now })
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **Model** object has not been set yet, you need to instantiate it when you are returning the **Create** view for a GET request :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(tbl_one tbl_one)
{
    return View(new tbl_one());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you probably shouldn't be doing it on the front end. If you make a hidden field on the front end with a hard-coded value like `DateTime.Now`, you will still have to check it in the back end to make sure someone isn't sending you a bad value as a security precaution. I would recommend simply setting it in the back end so you only have to worry about it once.